# What is the best way to loop over pandas columns for generating histograms?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to loop over all the columns in a dataframe, titled "Struct.DF" and generate a histogram plot for each column.

```
#This is a summary of columns

Struct_DF.columns

Index(['ID', 'lh_BA1_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA2_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA3a_ExV_Area',
   'lh_BA3b_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA4a_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA4p_ExV_Area',
   'lh_BA6_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA44_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA45_ExV_Area',
   ...
   'R_presubiculum_Vol_Adj', 'R_parasubiculum_Vol_Adj',
   'R_molecular_layer_HP_Vol_Adj', 'R_GC_ML_DG_Vol_Adj', 
'R_CA3_Vol_Adj',
   'R_CA4_Vol_Adj', 'R_fimbria_Vol_Adj', 'R_HATA_Vol_Adj',
   'R_Whole_hippocampus_Vol_Adj', 'eTIV'],
  dtype='object', length=735)

# Check for normalcy of distribution of each variable.

# Set the column names

columns= Struct_DF.columns

# Loop over all columns
#using 2x2 matrix representation of histrogram specified by firs two 
#digits of subplot index and third index specifies the plot number (eg. #221)

i = 221
for col in columns:
    plt.subplot(i)
    plt.hist(Struct_DF[col])
    i+=1
```

I get the following Error message:

```
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5
```

Is there a way to generate these plots side by side?

Note: the question has been edited based on a suggested answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Struct_DF.col` is equivalent to `Struct_DF['col']` that's why you get the error, there is no column `'col'`, what you want to do is `Struct_DF[col]`

To plot the histograms you can do:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df.columns), figsize=(5, 25))
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[col].hist(ax=axs[n])
```

If you want to use a 2x2 grid you can instead do like this, but you need to specify the 4 columns you want to plot:

```
cols_to_plot = ['lh_BA4a_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA4p_ExV_Area',
   'lh_BA6_ExV_Area', 'lh_BA44_ExV_Area']


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for n, col in enumerate(cols_to_plot):
    i, j = [int(l) for l in "{0:02b}".format(n)]
    df[col].hist(ax=axs[i][j])
```

You can also use `ax[i].hist(df[col])` instead of `df[col].hist(ax=ax[i])` or:

```
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    plt.hist(df[cols_to_plot[i]])
```

Comment: thanks! Using the syntax you suggested advances the loop, however, it errors out based on plotting. I get the following error: ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5. Do you know if there is a way to set for the plots to be side by side?

Comment: @dzang was right. I edited my question based on his helpful suggestion.